# AsyncStorage not functioning, errors and database input buttons freezing

Tags: node.js, react-native, expo, react-navigation, asyncstorage

So, I am currently working on a program that is supposed to be a mock-up of a Student Educational Plan for a school. The basic gist of it is that it displays a home page with buttons to a form to submit information (text input has buttons to submit or clear the information entered into the to an AsyncStorage database and a page that displays reports of information collected from the form. All pages display somewhat normally, but for some reason, when I press the submit button, the page freezes and does not submit the info. Here is the code I have as of right now. I am stuck trying to figure out how to use AsyncStorage in the context, which is why I don't have it added here. Another thing to add is that the names in the StyleSheet are the way they are is because I had originally based the code from a previous program (mock-up Music Player) I had worked on. Please explain everything as simply as possible.
Edit: I have tried to do more with the AsyncStorage, but the buttons don't work properly. Below is the edited version of the previous code.

```
import { Image, ScrollView, StyleSheet, Text, View, Button, TextInput,} from 'react-native';
//import {AsyncStorage} from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createNativeStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/native-stack';

const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator();

const MyStack = () => {

  
  
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator>
        <Stack.Screen
          name="Home"
          component={HomeScreen}
          options={{ title: 'Welcome' }}
        />
        <Stack.Screen name="SEP Form" component={SEPScreen} />
        <Stack.Screen name="SEP Database" component={SEPInfo} />
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
};

const HomeScreen = ({ navigation }) => {
  return (
    
    <View style={styles.container}>
    <Button
      title="Your Student Educational Plan"
      onPress={() =>
        navigation.navigate('SEP Form')
      }
    />
    <Button
      title="All Student Educational Plans"
      onPress={() =>
        navigation.navigate('SEP Database')
      }
    />
    </View>
  );
};


const SEPScreen = ({ navigation, route }) => {
  const[SEPInfo, setForm] = useState({});
  const save = async() => {
    try{
      await AsyncStorage.setItem(SEPInfo)
      if (SEPInfo.name == null || SEPInfo.name == '') {
        alert("Please Enter your Name");
      }
      else if (SEPInfo.id == null || SEPInfo.id == '') {
        alert("Please Enter your ID");
      }
      else if (SEPInfo.major == null || SEPInfo.major == '') {
        alert("Please Enter your Major");
      }
      else if (SEPInfo.goal == null || SEPInfo.goal == '') {
        alert("Please Enter your Goal");
      }
      else {
        await AsyncStorage.setItem("form", JSON.stringify(SEPInfo));
        alert(`Form Saved! Name: ${SEPInfo.name}\nID: ${SEPInfo.id}\nMajor: ${SEPInfo.major}\nGoal: ${SEPInfo.goal}`)
      }
    }
    catch (error) {
      alert(error);
    };
   /* const clear = async() => {
      try{
    await AsyncStorage.removeItem(SEPInfo);
    setForm({});
    alert('Form Cleared');
      }
      catch (error){
        alert(error);
      }
    }; */
    const load = async () => {
      try {
      let form = JSON.parse (await AsyncStorage.getItem(form));
      if (form !== null) {
        setForm(SEPInfo);
      }
    }
      catch (error) {
        alert(error);
      }
      
    };

  } 

 function clear () {
  setState({name:'', id:'', major:'', goal:''});
   alert('Form has been cleared!');

 }

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
  <Text style={styles.sectionTitle}>Enter your info here:</Text>

<TextInput style={styles.input} name="name" label="StudentName " placeholder="Name" onChangeText={(text) => setForm({...SEPInfo, name: text})} />
<TextInput style={styles.input} name="id" label="StudentID " placeholder="ID" onChangeNumber={(number) => setForm({...SEPInfo, id: number})} />
<TextInput style={styles.input} name="major" label="Major " placeholder="Major" onChangeText={(text) => setForm({...SEPInfo, major: text})} />
<TextInput style={styles.input} name="goal" label="Goal " placeholder="Goal" onChangeText={(text) => setForm({...SEPInfo, goal: text})} />
  <Button title="Submit"
  onPress={() => save()
  }
    ></Button>
  <Button title="Clear"
  onPress={clear}
  ></Button>
 </View>
  );
};

const SEPInfo = ({navigation, route}) => {
  return(
<View style={styles.container}>
<Text style={styles.sectionTitle}>SEP Database</Text>
</View>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#CFEAF1'
  },
  listWrapper: {paddingTop: 80, paddingHorizontal: 20},
  sectionTitle: {fontWeight: 'bold', fontSize: 30, margin: 5, color: '#2E2090', alignSelf: 'center'},
  sectionTitleTwo: {fontWeight: 'bold', fontSize: 25, margin: 5, color: '#206290', alignSelf: 'center'},
  flexContainerWaiting: {backgroundColor: '#20BD57', padding: 15, borderRadius: 10, flexDirection: 'row', alignItems: 'center', marginTop: 5, marginBottom: 5, justifyContent: 'space-evenly'},
  flexContainerOne: {backgroundColor: '#0B97B0', fontSize: 16, flex: 0.5, padding: 15, borderRadius: 10, flexDirection: 'row', alignItems: 'center', marginTop: 2.5, marginBottom: 2.5, justifyContent: 'space-evenly'},
  flexContainerTwo: {backgroundColor: '#D773EB', fontSize: 16, flex: 0.5, padding: 15, borderRadius: 10, flexDirection: 'row', alignItems: 'center', marginTop: 2.5, marginBottom: 2.5, justifyContent: 'space-evenly'},
  input: {
    height: 40,
    margin: 12,
    borderWidth: 1,
    padding: 10,
  },
});

export default MyStack;
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the AsyncStorage docs (https://reactnative.dev/docs/asyncstorage#setitem), it says that when using `setItem()`, you need to pass a `key: string` and a `value: string`. In your code, you only seem to pass a value: `AsyncStorage.setItem(TextInput)`. Furthermore, you pass the value `TextInput` into `setItem()`, but you don't seem to define `TextInput` anywhere. What you should do is use the `value` prop and `onChangeText` prop to store the value of the `TextInput` in a `state` variable, as is shown on the docs: https://reactnative.dev/docs/textinput. Then, pass that `state` variable into `setItem()` as they `value` and pass another item as its `key`.

Comment: So, I tried doing something of the sort, but it doesn't seem like the buttons are functioning properly. the submit button always returns that the id field has a null value and the clear button always gives out an error. Does this have to do with how everything is positioned? I edited this post to include the code I have as of right now.

Answer (score 0):

for saving an item in async storage:-

```
AsyncStorage.setItem('usertoken', token);
```

for fetching an item from async storage:-

```
// need to be called inside an async function
  let token = await AsyncStorage.getItem('userToken');
```